# NHibernate: Many-to-one IUserType

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, lazy-loading, many-to-one, iusertype

Following on from this question:

[NHibernate: Lazy loading of IUserType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286132/nhibernate-lazy-loading-of-iusertype)

Seeing as I can't lazy load a property or a one-to-one relationship, is there a way I can use an IUserType with a many-to-one? Something like this (which doesn't work):

```
<many-to-one
     name="Client" column="`ClientId`"
     lazy="true"
     type="EmployeeSystem.UserTypes.ClientUserType, EmployeeSystem" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like NHibernate does not support custom loading (`IUserType`) for associations (many-to-one, one-to-one etc). As a side note, lazy loading with one-to-one [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006030/maintaining-multiple-one-to-many/7006439#7006439), but again there is no way to put the `IUserType` hook. I think you were on the right track with lazy properties. Update the original question with the code that shows how you load Employee.

Comment: Yep, it can't be done. Looks like another dead end. NH can be frustraing sometimes. My current route is to create a proxy in NullSafeGet with an interceptor that loads the entity from the service when any properties other than ID are accessed.